# How to write the code of UIButton for all version of ios like ios6& ios7 3.5 inches and 4 inches screen

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I want to create an application that runs on both iPhone 4 and 5 and 3Gs also.I am writing like this.But it is not working good in ios 6 & ios7 4-inches screen. This is my code.help me any body.

```
#define IS_WIDESCREEN ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    if(IS_WIDESCREEN) {
        weeklyAudio=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [weeklyAudio addTarget:self action:@selector(weeklyPredictions)    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [weeklyAudio setTitle:@"WEEKLY PREDICTIONS" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        weeklyAudio.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        weeklyAudio.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
        [weeklyAudio.titleLabel setTextAlignment: NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        [weeklyAudio setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(60, 10, 10, 10)];
        [weeklyAudio.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0]];
        weeklyAudio.frame=CGRectMake(10, 70, 140, 100);
        weeklyAudio.layer.cornerRadius=5;
        weeklyAudio.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:232.0f/255.0f green:52.0f/255.0f blue:27.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
        [self.view addSubview:weeklyAudio];
        weeklyAudioImage=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, 10, 48, 48)];
        weeklyAudioImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"48*48.png"];
        [weeklyAudio addSubview:weeklyAudioImage];
    } else {
        weeklyAudio=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [weeklyAudio addTarget:self action:@selector(weeklyPredictions) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [weeklyAudio setTitle:@"WEEKLY PREDICTIONS" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        weeklyAudio.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        weeklyAudio.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
        [weeklyAudio.titleLabel setTextAlignment: NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        [weeklyAudio setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(60, 10, 10, 10)];
        [weeklyAudio.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0]];
        weeklyAudio.frame=CGRectMake(10, 70, 140, 100);
        weeklyAudio.layer.cornerRadius=5;
        weeklyAudio.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:232.0f/255.0f green:52.0f/255.0f blue:27.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
        [self.view addSubview:weeklyAudio];
        weeklyAudioImage=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, 10, 48, 48)];
        weeklyAudioImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"48*48.png"];
        [weeklyAudio addSubview:weeklyAudioImage];
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you point, what exactly is problem? 'Not working good' is not so explanatory.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the `xcode IDE` and in future please format your code correctly in your question.

Comment: thanks for responding bro.I got some alignment issues.like in ios 7 4-inches screen the button displayed some position. and ios 6 4-inches screen the button displayed some other position.That is my problem.But i want to display button same position in ios6 & ios7 4-inches screen.

Comment: Just a guess, did you take care of 20px status bar height that is separate from your view in iOS6 but is part of your view in iOS7? Try including screenshot for both cases in your question to explain it even better. Also, it seems you have written almost same code in both if-else part of your code.